# Add column names based on a row - R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this data frame:

```
data_df <- data.frame(requests = c(300,400,500),
                      approvals = c(35,48,52),
                      loans = c(14, 22, 23),
                      id_month = c("Jan-19","Feb-19","Mar-19"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to set the table using months as cols. So firstly I transposed it:

```
data_df %>% t()
```

This is the result:

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
requests  "300"    "400"    "500"   
approvals "35"     "48"     "52"    
loans     "14"     "22"     "23"    
id_month  "Jan-19" "Feb-19" "Mar-19"
```

But I don't know how to put row "id_month" as column header. Besides all values seem to be characters and not numbers (perhaps because each column contains a character row). This should be the expected result:

```
          Jan-19 Feb-19 Mar-19    
requests  300    400    500   
approvals 35     48     52    
loans     14     22     23
```

Any help in tidy verse will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_df %>% select(-4) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
names(df)<-data_df$id_month
df

          Jan-19 Feb-19 Mar-19
requests     300    400    500
approvals     35     48     52
loans         14     22     23
```

Comment: Thank you @Duck, works fine for a Tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `transpose` from `data.table`

```
out <- data.table::transpose(data_df, make.names = 'id_month')
row.names(out) <- names(data_df)[-4]
out
#          Jan-19 Feb-19 Mar-19
#requests     300    400    500
#approvals     35     48     52
#loans         14     22     23
```

If we don't need row names and would be okay with a column

```
data.table::transpose(data_df, make.names = 'id_month', keep.names = 'rn')
#         rn Jan-19 Feb-19 Mar-19
#1  requests    300    400    500
#2 approvals     35     48     52
#3     loans     14     22     23
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
`colnames<-`(t(data_df[-4]), data_df$id_month)
#          Jan-19 Feb-19 Mar-19
#requests     300    400    500
#approvals     35     48     52
#loans         14     22     23
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun, I will read more about data.table, it seems quite straightforward to use it.